# Composer init (new project) Aborted with Symfony RuntimeException

Tags: exception, composer-php

In a new folder completely empty :

`composer init`

i have :

```
Welcome to the Composer config generator

This command will guide you through creating your composer.json config.

Package name (<vendor>/<name>) [slordef/test-composer]:

  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
  Aborted

init [--name NAME] [--description DESCRIPTION] [--author AUTHOR] [--type [TYPE]] [--homepage HOMEPAGE] [--require REQUIRE] [--require-dev REQUIRE-DEV] [-s|--stability STABILITY] [-l|--license LICENSE] [--repository REPOSITORY]
```

Composer is up to date...
Dont know how it append

Comment: try running that command by adding `-vvv` to get debug output e.g: `composer init -vvv`

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a problem with PHP version 7.4, had to switch to version 7.3 to make it work

Comment: This solution fixes in my case, thank you.

Comment: I am using PHP 7.3.12 of wampserver 3 but still got that problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

by running :

```
composer init -vvv
```

get :

Exception trace:
 () at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/QuestionHelper.php:148
 Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper->doAsk() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/QuestionHelper.php:75
 Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper->Symfony\Component\Console\Helper{closure}() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/QuestionHelper.php:404
 Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper->validateAttempts() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/QuestionHelper.php:78
 Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper->ask() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/IO/ConsoleIO.php:291
 Composer\IO\ConsoleIO->askAndValidate() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/InitCommand.php:240
 Composer\Command\InitCommand->interact() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:230
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:835
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:185
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:267
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:106
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/bin/composer:61
 require() at C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar:24

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and reinstall Composer. Note that when installing, set php version 7.0. * To environment variables. So your problem will be solved

Comment: Why 7.0.*? Why not 7.4.*? Giving an example of what that looks would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same bug, but I after all I realized that it happens in the last version of php. Example: I am now using PHP 7.4 but when I switched to PHP 7.3.12 the bug was solved! So I could dare saying that for that specific bug the first thing to check is the version of PHP you're using whether is it stable of not..